# send a time value from jquery to a python server

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, google-app-engine

Say there is an event on 2nd August 2005 at 8:30 PM UTC. 
I want to send this value from jquery to django or webapp server, through a post request and update the server with the same value. 
How do i do it?

the way i tried doing it was:

```
$.post(
    url :"http://localhost:8080/m_post_data",
    data : {'start_date': "4/4/2012",
    'start_time': "14:30:00"})
```

and in the views (currently webapp2, on appengine) i try the following:

```
class PostDataMatch(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def post(self):
    mat = Match(
      start_date = self.request.get('start_date'),
      start_time = self.request.get('start_time'),
    )
    mat.put()

    self.response.write(self.request.get('start_time'))
```

The model definition is as follows:

```
class Match(db.Model):
    start_date = db.DateProperty()
    start_time = db.TimeProperty()
```

but this gives an error:

```
BadValueError: Property start_time must be a time
```

How should i try fixing it?

Answer (score 3):

1. You should use the DateTime property instead of two properties
2. You should [parse the string into datetime object](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) (using strptime)

Comment: yes that is an option, but is there any way of doing it on the client side itself, i the javascript value i send itself is a dateproperty?

Comment: And then format it back to a string to be able to send it to the server? Better stay with Shay's proposal.

Comment: could you please take the above date in the question and paste a snippet i have been trying to convert for the last hour and getting errors one after another.

Answer (score 1):

Better this:

```
from dateutil import parser
start_date = self.request.get('start_date')
start_time = self.request.get('start_time')
tm = start_date + " " + start_time
parser.parse(tm)
```

sample output:

```
In [28]: strn = '4/5/2012 14:30:00'

In [29]: parser.parse(strn)
Out[29]: datetime.datetime(2012, 4, 5, 14, 30)
```

or without dateutil:

```
In [62]: start_date
Out[62]: '4/4/2012'

In [63]: start_time
Out[63]: '14:30:00'

In [64]: date_time = start_date+" "+start_time

In [65]: datetime.strptime(date_time, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
Out[65]: datetime.datetime(2012, 4, 4, 14, 30)
```